# blackberry, make call when label clicked

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to make a label containing a number clickable so when the user clicks the label a telephone number is called (or the option to call is shown to the user). When I click the label at the moment i just get a tooltip kind of menu with the option to copy the number...

```
private LabelField contactPhoneNumberField = new LabelField(number,Field.FOCUSABLE)
{
        protected boolean navigationClick()
        {
            // write your code on click
            // make the call
            PhoneArguments callArgs = new PhoneArguments(
                PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, number);
            Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, callArgs);
            return true;
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that execution flow does not enter your `navigationClick()` method, and due to this fact you get tooltip instead of wanted functionality.

Seems that the click event does not reach your label instance, and it is consumed before. For instance by the container class instance (screen/manager).

Check `naviagationClick()` method of the container screen class/manager instance and make sure that your label instance gets the click event.

Answer (score 2):

```
final LabelField contactPhoneNumberField = new LabelField("",Field.FOCUSABLE) {
public boolean navigationClick (int status , int time){
    PhoneArguments callArgs = new PhoneArguments(
    PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, number);
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, callArgs);
    return true;
```

}
    };

After playing around for a while it turned out i needed to add the int status and int time parameters

Comment: Yes, because otherwise you did not override navigationClick() method, but created a new one with different signature.

Comment: Carl, can you mark this answer as the solution (accept by clicking the little "V" icon next to the answer)?  That way, we know that you don't need any more help with this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A piece of advice. You should not use navigationClick() to handle clicks. Override the navigationUnclick() method instead and handle the Unclick.

1. This conforms to the standard user interface behavior. Almost all native fields like Buttons, listfields on blackberry do the action on the unclick and not on the click. Even buttons and links on windows follow the same concept.
2. If you take some action on the navigationClick() that changes the focus - like push a new screen, the navigationUnclick will be called on the new field in focus. If that field is a Button, that button will get clicked.
3. If the focus does not change, then the navigationUnclick() will return unhandled. This will result in the screen's navigationUnclickUnhandled() which will show the "tooltip kind of menu".